# NetBeans New WebService Warning Message In Java EE

Tags: java, web, netbeans-8

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \wsdls\wsat10\wsat.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188) [wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    ... 27 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \wsdls\wsc11\wstx-wscoor-1.1-wsdl-200702.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188) [wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: just some log files are not going to help, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know why it's exist and how to remove it, because I worry that this warning will effect to my system when log file increase day by day.